# Hyper-V Server 2016 vSwitch (external) doesn't get IP from DHCP server. Even a Static IP doesn't connect the VM to my network

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

Setting up Hyper-V Server 2016 in a Dell PowerEdge R740. Installation went well.

Set-up a VM after creating a virtual switch (external) using Hyper-V Manager. Though external, the virtual network adapter was not getting an IP from my DHCP. I setup a static IP for that vNIC to see if it gets a  connection to the gateway but didn't. Hyper-V manager was still showing APIPA in the networking tab and I had to restart the VM to see the change in Hyper-V manager.

when I checked the network settings from the Hyper-V sconfig window it was showing APIPA instead of the static IP address i assigned for that virtualEthernet.

[sconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j3yM.png)
[Hyper-V Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of3Zt.png)